# User Dictionary as a Type Parameter using Generics

Tags: c#, generics, type-parameter

I am creating an interface IDataStore which defines the 'Type' of Data Store and the ReturnType. I can then create a class say Service, which implements the IDataStore in order to serve data.

Here is my Interface:

```
public interface IDataStore<TData, out TReturnType>
    where TData : struct, IEnumerable
    where TReturnType : struct
{
    TData Data { get; set; }
    void ClearData();
    void LoadData();
    TReturnType Get(object key);
}
```

Here is my service interface that will contain the data store:

```
public interface ICommunication
{
    void Start();

    void Stop();
}

public interface IDataServer<TDataStoreType, TReturnType> : ICommunication
        where TDataStoreType : struct, IEnumerable
        where TReturnType : struct
{
        IDataStore<TDataStoreType, TReturnType> DataStore { get; set; }
}
```

Here is my implementation Service:

```
public class PipeServer<TDataStoreType, TReturnType> : IDataServer<TDataStoreType, TReturnType>
    where TReturnType : struct
    where TDataStoreType : struct, IEnumerable
{
    public IDataStore<TDataStoreType, TReturnType> DataStore { get; set; }

    public string PipeName { get; set; }

    public short MaxThreads
    {
        get { return _maxThreads; }
        set { _maxThreads = value > (short)254 ? (short)254 : value; }
    }

    public DataLoadType DataLoadType
    {
        get { return ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DataLoadType"].AsDataLoadType(); }
    }

    public PipeServer(string pipeName, short maxThreads = 254)
    {
        PipeName = pipeName;
        MaxThreads = maxThreads;
        _logger = new EventLogger();
    }

    private void ServerLoop()
    {
        while (_running)
        {
            ProcessNextClient();
        }

        _terminateHandle.Set();
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        if (DataStore == null)
            throw new Exception("Data store not assigned to this server. Please set the 'DataStore' property before staring the server so that data can be served.");
        _running = true;
        _runningThread = new Thread(ServerLoop);
        _runningThread.Start();
        _logger.InfoFormat("Clients: {0}", _clientCount);
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        _running = false;
        _logger.Info("Initiating Service Stop.");
        //create a fake client to End Wait for Connection.
        var pc = new PipeClient(PipeName);
        pc.Start();
        pc.Stop();

        _terminateHandle.WaitOne();
    }

    public virtual string ProcessRequest(string message)
    {
        return "";
    }

    public void ProcessClientThread(object o)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var pipeStream = (NamedPipeServerStream)o)
            using (var br = new BinaryReader(pipeStream))
            using (var bw = new BinaryWriter(pipeStream))
            {
                if (pipeStream.IsConnected)
                {
                    _clientCount++;
                    Console.WriteLine("Clients: {0}", _clientCount);
                    _logger.InfoFormat("Clients: {0}", _clientCount);
                }
                while (pipeStream.IsConnected)
                {
                    var k = br.ReadString();
                    if (k.Length == 1)
                        continue;

                    bw.Write(DataStore.Get(k));
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Client Disconnected. Current Connected Clients: {0}", --_clientCount);
            _logger.InfoFormat("Client Disconnected. Current Connected Clients: {0}", _clientCount);
        }
    }

    public void ProcessNextClient()
    {
        try
        {
            var pipeStream = new NamedPipeServerStream(PipeName, PipeDirection.InOut, MaxThreads);
            pipeStream.WaitForConnection();

            //Spawn a new thread for each request and continue waiting
            var t = new Thread(ProcessClientThread);
            t.Start(pipeStream);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //If there are no more avail connections (254 is in use already) then just keep looping until one is avail
            Console.WriteLine("No More Connections Available: {0}", ex.Message);
            _logger.WarningFormat("No More Connections Available: {0}", ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private short _maxThreads;
    private bool _running;
    private Thread _runningThread;
    private readonly EventWaitHandle _terminateHandle = new EventWaitHandle(false, EventResetMode.AutoReset);
    private readonly ILogger _logger;
    private int _clientCount;
}
```

Now that my skeleton is laid out, when I try to create an instance of PipeServer as below:

```
private static ICommunication PipeServer = new PipeServer<IDictionary<string, short>, short>("DHM");
```

Visual Studio complains about:

> Error 5   The type 'System.Collections.Generic.IDictionary' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'TDataStoreType' in the generic type or method 'PipeServer'

Any help or inputs on this will be great. Thanks Pardon me if my point is not clear. I will update the question with additional details.

Comment: Did you mean to put the `struct` constraint on `TDataStoreType`? That's what's causing the error

Comment: Why do you have `struct` restrictions on your generic types?

Comment: I added struct as I read through few other posts on SO. I did not have them before and they would still complain. Infact i did not even want to put any constraints..

Comment: You guys were right. I might have fixed it accidentally after adding the struct constraint. Thanks.